# split function does not work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, split, jquery-events

I'm trying to catch selected items from a multiple select for inserting them into another select input. The thing is that when I try to split the selected elements with `split` function the console throws me the next error: `Uncaught TypeError: strValue.split is not a function`

### HTML

```
<select multiple id="e9" name="musc_group[]">
    <option value="Chest">Chest</option>
    <option value="Back">Back</option>
</select>
```

### JAVASCRIPT

```
$("#e9").change(function(){
    var strValues = $(this).val(); // This gives you the string "Chest,Back"
    var arrValues = strValues.split(",");          
});
```

Out of the event all works fine but not within it.

Comment: `// This gives you the string "Chest,Back" OR undefined`...

Comment: Why do you think `.val()` gave the string `"Chest,Back"`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) returns an array of values for `select[multiple]` elements.

From the docs:

> The `.val()` method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as `input`, `select` and `textarea`. **In the case of `select` elements, it returns `null` when no option is selected and an array containing the value of each selected option when there is at least one and it is possible to select more because the `multiple` attribute is present.**

(emphasis mine)

What this means is that your comment of `// This gives you the string "Chest,Back"` is incorrect, because you're actually getting an array that you're probably casting to a string (with `alert`?)

Answer (score 0):

You are already getting an array of values, the reason being that in select option you can allow for multiple choices, and which you are by using `multiple` attribute on `select` element. So value is always returned in form of array, as how else would it better to return multiple values.

So no need to split, it's already an array.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple select returns an array not a string,

```
$("#e9").change(function(){
    var strValues = $(this).val(); // This gives you the string "Chest,Back"

    alert(strValues[0]);
    alert(strValues[1]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`.val()`  return  a array of selected elements. so, you need not `split` function. and a array element show as a string join of `,` . you may miss understand.